# Matlab process big data

Tags: matlab, bigdata

I have to read and then process a huge amount of data (Matrix: ~40.000.000x19).

Frist step is to read the data:

```
Array = load('vort.dat');
```

The flie 'vort.dat ' contains ~40.000.000 (imax*jmax*kmax) lines and 19 rows, the first line is:

```
 3.53080034E-03   0.00000000       1.25000002E-02   63.0216064      -3.03968048      -358.802948      -744.902588      -2.51340670E-10   2.11566061E-04   18.6898212       72.3569489      0.727692425      0.754972637      0.661218643       1.50408816       1.87408039E-03 5.69900125E-03   0.00000000       0.00000000
```

Than I loop over the Array and store the various values for the post-processing into separate arrays:

```
imax=511;
jmax=160;
kmax=399;
for q=1:length(Array(:,1))
    Rp(k,j,i)=Array(q,1);
    yp(k,j,i)=(0.5-Rp(k,j,i))*360;
    ...

    % index variables
    k=k+1;
    if(k>kmax)
        k=1;
        i=i+1;
        if(i>imax)
            i=1;
            j=j+1;
            if(j>jmax)
                j=1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Than the post-processing starts!

The problem is that matlab crashes without a warning during the data processing or during the plotting of figures!

I already set the stack size to unlimitied (ulimit -s unlimited).

The second idea was working with memmapfile, it looks like it is working but the plots from the post-processing show that it does not read the right data!

```
%%% Array = load('vort.dat');
m=memmapfile('data.dat','Format',{'double',[imax*jmax*kmax 19], 'x'},'repeat', 1);
Array=m.data.x;
```

Comment: Optimizing the memory use depends strongly on your particular calculations. Your post says a lot about index variables (which take at most 8 bytes each) and almost nothing about the content variables `Array`, `Rp`, `yp` etc. which take a lot of memory. Does the post-processing still needs `Array`?

Comment: @CST-Link I dont need the Array "Array" anymore in my pos-processing. I well add one line of 'vort.dat' to the original post!

Comment: Please use `if`statements like they're meant to: with `ifelse`. Don't nest three `if`s, just use `if %something elseif %somethingelse elseif %thirdpossibility end`. In the case of 40M rows, I'd go with a `fread` statement, read some lines, process them, dump them from memory, read the next lines, process them, dump them from memory etc.

Comment: @Adriaan ok I fixed that! Any idea what I do wrontg with 'memmapfile'?

Comment: Matlab isn't the best when it comes to large amounts of data. (this is hugely dependent on what version you have!), so my suggestion is to load it in chunks, process it down and load in the other chunk. Do multiple data writes if you need.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Yes I think there is no other way to do this ... The problem is matlab makes this amazing 3D plots in no time ... do you know a better software ( I tried gnuplot but it is not capable of doing the 3D contour plots I would like to do ..)

Comment: @chi86 I use Apache Spark for big data processing, all my modelling/feature extraction are done in Spark (on the cloud - 100GB of data crushed into a few MB of significance in a matter of few hours). After which I use matlab to do some post processing and (very occasionally) plotting. I use Julia or R for most of my plots, but don't get me wrong, I use Matlab all the time, I just use it to simulate my algorithms before writing them in Java/Scala Spark.

Comment: @GameOfThrows thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running out of memory during pre-processing, you may want to clear MATLAB's memory before loading massive amounts of data:

```
clear('all');
Array = load('vort.dat');
%'Here continues the pre-processing'
```

If you're running out of memory during post-processing, you may want to clear massive variables once they're not used anymore. For example, since `Array` is not used anymore after pre-processing, begin your post-processing with:

```
clear('Array');
```

or, simpler:

```
Array = 0;
```

Given the size of your matrix, this should free enough memory to allow you carry on with post-processing and reporting.

So, as example, the script would look like:

```
%//Preparing
clear('all');           %//Start with fresh memory
dbstop('if', 'error');  %//Trap uncaught exceptions

%//Loading
A = load('vort.dat');

%//Pre-processing, vectorized operations
I = 511;
J = 160;
K = 399;
Rp = permute(reshape(A(:,1),K,I,J), [1 3 2]);
yp = (0.5 - Rp)*360;
%//...

%//Post-processing
clear('A');   %//and other vars not needed anymore
%//...
```

Comment: Ok I did that but still matlab crashed saying: Killed!

Comment: @chi86 That doesn't sound like a standard MATLAB error. Are you using custom functions to do the post-processing? if yes, use `dbstop if error` to trap the first error that will crash the execution (i.e. that will not be handled), then see from there what you can do. It is impossible right now, with only the information that you provided, to say what is the issue. But the thing is -- again, a matter of using carefully your resources: clear variables that are unnecessary, save intermediate results to files to avoid computing them again, process data in chunks.

Comment: thx! I just use matlab standard function and plots ... I will try to improve my code as you said and I also try it on a computer with more resources maybe that helps!

Comment: I finally got it running with the code you gave me but it still is crashing with the statement: "Killed"